# My regex does not work

Tags: java, regex

This code does not return the correct result:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^[y]{1,4}$|^[m]{1,4}$|^[d]{1,4}$");

String text1="yyyy";
String text2="mmm";

Matcher m=p.matcher(text);
boolean b=m.find();
System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));

m=p.matcher(text2);
b=m.find();
System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));
```

The line `System.out.println(String.valueOf(b));` prints `false`  I want it to return `true`.  Does anyone see what's wrong with the code?

Comment: What kind of JVM are you using?

Comment: @KARASZI jdk1.6.0 update20 i am using

Comment: This should work as expected on that one. Are you sure the problem is here? Could you compile and run only this example code and check?

Comment: It would be nice to see the imports as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler regex could be:

```
^(y{1,4}|m{1,4}|d{1,4})$
```

*UPDATE1:* I've checked your regex as well, and it's syntactically correct but maybe the Java regex engine does not like it.

*UPDATE2:* I even checked your Java code and it works for me with only one exception that in the first part it's `text1` instead of `text` what you've typed.

It prints out `true` for me in my JVM, so the problem is probably not with your regex.